# Qt - Problems while serializing "double"

Tags: c++, qt, serialization

I serialize "double" data type and get an error though

```
 QDataStream & operator<< ( double f )
```

operator is defined. Here is the error message:

```
 error: conversion from 'double' to 'const QChar' is ambiguous
```

Did you meat this situation or understand why it can be like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like it can't see the operator for double, so it's trying to implicitly create a `QChar` from the double to send to the stream, but `QChar` has multiple constructors that could possibly match.

Make sure that your header includes are all correct.

Can you show us the code where you're trying to serialize the double?

Comment: Very logical and right! Thanks. I forgot to includ QDataStream.

Answer (score -1):

You might find it useful to write any double-literals (if you're using any) with the decimal portion as well, i.e.

```
ds << 0.0;
```

Rather than

```
ds << 0;
```

It probably won't solve your problem, but it'll cut down any ambiguity!